# Will Ubuntu install necessary drivers for my Computer?

Tags: installation, drivers

I am planning on installing ubuntu removing the existing windows vista.

My question is, will ubuntu detect my hardware and install the necessary drivers ?

Comment: How can we tell you without knowing your hardware specifications. Please give us your hardware details

Answer (score 3):

Probably - yes.

The best way to make sure is to boot your Ubuntu CD/USB and select 'Try Ubuntu'.
This will load a live session and so you can make sure everything works.

You can also check the 'additional drivers' application to see if additional proprietary drivers are available for you hardware if needed:

- [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)